# Casting pointer to long *

Tags: c, pointers

I observed some code today (I cannot disclose the entire block of code), but the idea was as follows:

```
// arr is a char array

*((long *) (arr + <hex offset e.g. 0x10>)) = <hex address e.g. 0xbffcc210>;
```

I was wondering why the address was cast to `(long *)`. Does it have anything to do with endianess ?

Comment: Where you wrote "hex address",must actually be an integer

Answer (score 0):

The code treating the memory location **arr + hex offset** as containing a long integer value.  It is setting that location to **hex address**.  A given memory address can be treated as containing character, integer, float, structure, etc. if necessary.

It does not have to do with endianness, though the order of the bytes in memory does change depend on the endianness.  The contents of memory will be different on a big endian vs. little endian machine.

For example, if you store 0x90ab12cd as an unsigned 4 byte integer to address 1000, in a big endian system memory will look like:

```
1000: 90
1001: ab
1002: 12
1003: cd
```

On a little endian system it would look like:

```
1000: cd
1001: 12
1002: ab
1003: 90
```

[Source](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html)

Comment: Not the content will be different - just its representation.

Comment: note: because of the strict aliasing rule, this only works if either `0x1000` is a variable declared as `long`, or part of `malloc`'d space

Answer (score 0):

Does it have anything to do with endianess ?

No because changing the pointer type doesn't modifies the endianess of memory location. The address was cast to a long because they wanted to access a value of type `long`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some raw memory represented by array `arr` and want to write forth (`sizeof(long) == 4`) or second (if `sizeof(long) == 8`) word, this code will do it.

But depending on endianness, and `sizeof(long)` you will get different bytes overwritten:

[image: a table of cells]

where LE and BE is endianness and last digit is `sizeof(long)`